# Android Studio Updated Error https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3.2-all.zip

Tags: android, gradle, updates

I have updated Android Studio and I get the following error:

```
Error:Cause: https://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.3.2-all.zip
```

I have internet access, I have cleaned and rebuilt the project and it is not solved

Answer (score 0):

You can try [downloading it](https://gradle.org/releases) manually and then copying to the

```
.gradle\wrapper\dists
```

Comment: The Wrapper folder did not have it, I created it by hand and I saved it inside the decompressed download and without decompressing (version 2.3.2 is not, I've put the 2.3 and 3.2) I still get the error